# New Django app initial DB migrations of an existing database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-2.0

I have an existing database filled with a bunch of data. I want to migrate to Django so I went ahead and created the necessary models with `python manage.py inspectdb`. I haven't changed anything besides removed the `managed = False` since I want Django to manage the tables (mistake perhaps for initial migration?).

So now that the models are ready, how can I generate the first migration file so that I can start changing the fields to generate additional migrations (renaming a field here and there). I understand `python manage.py migrate` will handle the creation of Django-specific models but does not actually create any migration files? Some sources indicate the first migration file should be run with `--fake` so it's not applied. Will the next migration files remember to run the first one as fake and only apply the next ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `makemigrations` to create the migrations. The `migrate` command applies migrations, it does not create them.

You can use the [`--fake-initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake-initial) option so that Django does not try to create the tables that already exist. Note that `--fake` and `--fake-initial` are two different commands.

When you run `migrate`, the `django_migrations` table is updated to store the currently applied migrations. The migration files themselves are not changed. The `--fake` command updates the `django_migrations` table without running the migration. That means that if you use it incorrectly your database and `django_migrations` table can get out of sync, which can be difficult to fix.

Comment: So for a new project, the process should be: `makemigrations <app>`, `migrate <app> --fake`, and then `migrate` to create the Django-specific tables? After that I can alter the models, run `makemigrations <app>; migrate` again, correct?

Comment: You've missed my suggestion to use `--fake-initial`, but that would work, as long as you run `migrate --fake` before you making alterations and running `makemigrations` again.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought `--fake` was a shorthand for `--fake-initial` but it actually creates the Django-specific tables so no need to run an extra migrate. Thank you! It seems to make a bit more sense now.